# Apache2 (rewrite_mod) - правильная настройка сайта

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

Есть сайт, который состоит из двух директорий:

```
public (публичный)
app (ядро / компоненты / конфиги)
```

В директории public находится index.php (который подключает роутер) + `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

В app - `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
```

Нужно сделать, чтобы все запросы переадресовывались на public.

Как правильнее и безопаснее настроить сайт, и есть ли разница настраивать в конфигах сайта или через файлики .htaccess?

Comment: К то по может   ?

Answer (score 0):

Смените в конфигурации `DocumentRoot` на этот самый каталог `public`, да и всё - и ненужно никаких Rewrite-ов.

`.htaccess` лучше никогда не использовать в продакшене - т.к. даёт довольно [неслабую просадку в производительности веб-сервера](http://www.eschrade.com/page/why-you-should-not-use-htaccess-allowoverride-all-in-production/).

Comment: Если я в DocumentRoot site/public напишу, у меня будут подключаться файлы с папки app из public/index.php или я что-то не правильно думаю?

Не совсем понимаю работу этого всего, т.к. много ньюансов учитывать приходится, но думаю 2 редиректа это уже не правильно.

Comment: Кончено будут подключатся. Rewrite-ы никак не связаны с работой php.

Comment: А DocumentRoot прописывать в .conf файлике сайта? Извините, что задаю такие глупые вопросы, хочу досконально разобраться

Comment: @Vova, да, именно там.

Comment: И все файлики .htaccess оставлять как есть? Или они уже не нужны?

Comment: @Vova, смотря что там у вас. Но вообще, всё спокойно переносится в из .htaccess в конфиги сайтов.

Comment: Попробовал, в итоге ничего не произошло.

Comment: @Vova, а веб-сервер перезапускали? Иначе быть такого не может, что бы ничего не изменилось

Comment: Да перезапускал, выводит что нет index файлика, а при запросе site/public кидает на public, без дописанного пути было тоже самое.